# GCC last update on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, gcc

I updated my gcc on linux mint but when I checked it seems wasn't installed. What is the problem?

```
joseph@joseph:~$ sudo apt install gcc-9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-9 is already the newest version (9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  codeblocks-common libcodeblocks0 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 240 not upgraded.

joseph@joseph:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 3):

Debian-based distros can have multiple versions of the same software.

Check for `/usr/bin/gcc`. You will see, that it is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/gcc`, which is a symlink to `/usr/bin/gcc-7`.

The command `update-alternatives --config gcc` will give you the option to choose the correct version.

If you remove gcc-7, it will automatically choose another alternative.